# Is there a way in c++ to make a custom gui with buttons and scrollbars without using windows api?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I know theres software like QT, GTK and wxwidgets but is there a way to make a window with buttons on windows without using the windows api in c++?

Comment: What's wrong with the 3 options you mentioned?

Comment: You listed the four main options. Why are they excluded? What are you looking for?

Comment: If you're wondering how those libraries do what they do, and if you can implement the same thing yourself, then yes, you can.  But it involves the Windows API.  You really can't do anything interesting whatsoever on Windows without the Windows API.  You're using it, one way or the other.  If you aren't using it directly, then the library you are using is using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can build your own UI Solution also, which you can use to make GUI for the software you like (not a big deal!), apart from those you mentioned above there are lot of other options available i.e.

1. Juce Graphics library
2. Minigui
3. SDL
4. ultimate++

etc

If you share your criteria and use case we may recommend you a better option as per your need.

Comment: I would like to create a custom gui software to make gui's for other software in c++ id rather not use anyone elses libraries, would like to learn it myself

Comment: Well, its not that difficult, first decide you need to go for rendering library or widget tool kit, then you are ready to take of! There are lot of examples of both, initially i would suggest to look through them and then decide to build your own!

Answer (score 2):

Creating visual forms with C++ involves:

- a toolkit such as QT, GTK or wxWidgets, or
- raw use of the native OS API

If you're looking to do it without any of those things, you're basically out of luck.

Comment: @user1887092 You're not ready to create an equivalent of Qt, GTK or wxWidgets. Sorry. And, even if you were, you'd then be using the Windows API which you threw out in your question.